# Is it possible to connect a backend MVC C# API with a separate frontend React project?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, minimal-apis

I am trying to create a conceptual diagram after researching for a while, it seems like you need to use minimal API if you want to mesh it with a React frontend. Is it possible to do this with the MVC architectural pattern?

I have read the docs and watched numerous tutorials but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you want an "MVC architectural pattern"?  I think the way to do this is with a ASP API backend.  If you are not familiar with an ASP API it has the feel of a MVC app and might be what you're looking for?

Take a look at this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

This link shows you how to easily get a template solution setup with a React SPA and a ASP.NET Core API project as the backend.

Comment: I would also add this tutorial from Microsoft: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and also how to deal with controllers if you need to include them but without Views in the MVC [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)